# Argparse add argument with choices and save to variable (dest)

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to add arguments to my code and I could make the following code work:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_parser('title', help='Top level arg')
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='my_var') # so I can access it later

subcommand_parser = subparser.add_parser('subtitle', help='Another option help', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
```

So with this I can call my program as follow:

```py
./main.py title subtitle foo
```

and then access the value passed in `if my_var == 'foo': ...`

The issue is that I want to get rid of the subtitle/parser and just call my program using `./main.py title foo` AND store that value in a variable

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_parser('title', help='Top level arg')
parser.add_argument('subtitle', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
```

which works great because I can call using `./main.py title foo (or bar)` but I loose access to the variable `args.my_var`

I tried adding `dest='my_var'` to add_parser but I get an unexpected argument error. I tried adding it to `add_argument` but I got a `dest supplied twice for positional argument` (I can probably get around this by adding `--` prior to the argument, but then I'm back at my initial problem).

Is there a way to call my program using `./main.py title foo` and save it to a variable such as `args.my_var`?

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('title', help='Top level arg')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
sp1 = sp.add_parser('subtitle')
sp1.add_argument('myvar', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

'title' is a positional argument, required

'cmd' is the subparser (also a positional, with choices)

'myvar' is a positional argument of the `subtitle` parser, which has two choices.

The:

```
sp1.add_argument('myvar', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
```

syntax applies to both a main parser and a subparser.

sample calls

top level help:

```
2126:~/mypy$ python3 stack71851214.py -h
usage: stack71851214.py [-h] title {subtitle} ...

positional arguments:
  title       Top level arg
  {subtitle}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

subcommand help:

```
2126:~/mypy$ python3 stack71851214.py atitle subtitle -h
usage: stack71851214.py title subtitle [-h] {foo,bar}

positional arguments:
  {foo,bar}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

subcommand with correct choice:

```
2126:~/mypy$ python3 stack71851214.py atitle subtitle foo
Namespace(cmd='subtitle', myvar='foo', title='atitle')
```

subcommand with wrong choice:

```
2127:~/mypy$ python3 stack71851214.py atitle subtitle baz
usage: stack71851214.py title subtitle [-h] {foo,bar}
stack71851214.py title subtitle: error: argument myvar: invalid choice: 'baz' (choose from 'foo', 'bar')
```

### edit

I don't understand your:

```
parser.add_parser('title', help='Top level arg')
```

That raises:

```
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_parser'
```

`add_parser` is a method of an Action created by `subparser = parser.add_subparsers`.  It is not a method of a `parser`.  Is this actually what you tested, or is it something you wrote for the question without testing?